# Is there a real substance called "bismullah"?

Tags: short-stories, science

In a science fiction story "Schedule" by Harry Walton, June, 1945, Earthmen trade for a substance callled "bismullah", mined on Rhea, a moon of Saturn.

And I assumed that that bismullah was the element bismuth, until I noticed the spelling difference.

Bismillah is an Arabic phrase "in the name of Allah".  And Bismullah seems to be an alternate spelling of bismillah.

So I wonder if the substance bismullah is just a fictional science fiction substance or a real substance.

Comment: Normally I’m all in favor of questions that can be answered in a web search. In this case it seems like a dictionary lookup is sufficient. If it were real, I expect someone would have put it into a dictionary or Wikipedia by now. If we still feel like answering this here, then doesn’t it at least come close to being a real world science question?

Comment: I've swapped [tag:substance] for [tag:science] so as not to overspecialise with a new tag. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't think it's outrageous to think maybe it's a spelling that disappeared since the 40s, or a non-English word for something that Walton used that never made it into English references (esp if it was an Arabic word, which uses a different writing system).

Comment: Bismullah? No. We will not let you go.

Comment: There's also the possibility that it's the name of the ore, not the valuable element in the ore, the same way *bauxite* doesn't sound anything like *aluminum*.

Answer (score 31):

In the story bismullah is described as "a radioactive rare earth". None of the rare earths have this name, or anything close to it. However, by 1945, when the story was written, one rare earth element had yet to be discovered (and named): element 61 now called promethium (Pm). So either bismullah is Walton's suggestion of a name for element 61, or a completely fictional substance.

Comment: And, oddly enough, all of promethium's isotopes are radioactive.

Comment: @EvilSnack In this story, the bismullah was used in face cream. Not advisable with promethium!

Comment: You say that in the story it is described as a radioactive rare earth, and it's used in face cream? Maybe it's not as bad as promethium would be, but I'd steer clear of slathering anything notably radioactive on me.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez That didn't stop them with [radium](https://cosmeticsandskin.com/aba/glowing-complexion.php).

Comment: @EvilSnack in the early XX century people were adding radioactive stuff everywhere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_quackery

Comment: @EvilSnack You might want to look at [this](https://www.orau.org/health-physics-museum/collection/consumer/index.html). Radioactive consumer products have not been uncommon.

Comment: Yes, but once the dangers became known, the use of radioactive substances in consumer products was drastically cut back and the remaining uses put under strict guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

### Out-of-universe reason

Before globalisation and before the Western world had the level of contact with and information on other cultures they do nowadays, it was common to borrow names that sounded "exotic" to the writer's - and reader's - ear, in order to denote something similarly exotic and otherworldly. It's highly likely that this was why the word ended up in the book, and that *bismullah* is an alternative transliteration of *bismillah* - maybe even the most common at the time, just like *Moslem* used to be the preferred transliteration for *Muslim* and *Koran* for *Qur'an*.

As a side note, the original Arabic that the transliteration comes from looks like this when spelt out:

بسم الله

And also has a [Unicode symbol](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FDFD) for the more calligraphic script that it usually appears in throughout the Qur'an:

﷽

Actually, technically, the Unicode version corresponds to the more complete version:

بسم الله الرحمنِ الرحيم

Most commonly translated as: *In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful*

Answer (score 1):

“Bismullah” doesn’t match the naming pattern of chemical elements, but in the story, it might be a trade name for some compound containing rare-earth elements.  Either way, it’s fictional.

On top of being a pun on *bismuth*, you mention it’s used as a cosmetic.  As I understand it, one time Arabs often say “bismillah” is when they leave the house, which they likely would do soon after putting on their makeup, and it can also be used when admiring something beautiful.  (I’m sure there are many nuances that I don’t understand.)

Comment: This is the same "bismillah" used in "Bohemian Rhapsody"?

Comment: @Barmar Yep, it means "in the name of Allah", a common opening for prayers.

Comment: @Barmar I don’t know of another. If one were to absolutely insist on trying to make literal sense of the lyrics to “Bohemian Rhapsody”: someone might be saying “Bismillah” because he’s a Muslim trying to begin a journey. In context, he could be declaring his intent to leave, and being told, “No! We will not let you go!”

Comment: FWIW, Freddie Mercury (aka Farrokh Bulsara) was born on Zanzibar, which is predominantly a conservative Muslim region. However, his parents were Parsees (Zoroastrian), and he went to an Anglican school, but he was most certainly familiar with Muslim culture, so it's hardly surprising for him to use the term "Bismillah" in *Bohemian Rhapsody*. See https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-45900712

Answer (score 0):

In the story, bismullah is "a radioactive rare earth" mined on Rhea and used in face creams (!). The story was written in 1945 when the standards for realism in SF were still *very* low.  (It is true that it appeared in *Astounding* which was better than most for taking care with the science in stories, it was still 1945 when most of Campbell's great writers were still involved in the War and not writing SF.)

Isn't the most likely explanation -- albeit an out-of-universe one -- that Walton was looking for a name and the word "bismullah" popped into his head and he thought that that sounded pretty good and sort of scientific, and went on writing?

"Bismullah" is not the common name of any real substance in use in 1945, and certainly not that of any radioactive isotope.